# Xamarin Visual Studio Emulator Problems

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I am a beginner getting into android development. When I create a project using xamarin forms, and I try to create an emulator, I get this error:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this? I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community.

Comment: Forgot to say, when I click reinstall in the error message, it still gives the same error again

Comment: The same issue as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302882/android-emulator-not-working-with-xamarin-visual-studio-mac

Comment: Yes, but there's no answer there?

Comment: That's why I can't mark your question as duplicate.

Comment: @user769321 Have you install all the SDK of API 28? You could check with below: VS> Tool> Android> Android SDK Manager Have try to create the different emulator with different API version? Does it throw the same error? We need mode details. Does your PC support Hyper-V? If yes, follow the stpes to use it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows

Comment: @Wedy Zang I tried it with different APIs, but still got the same error. I'm not sure how to check if my PC supports Hyper-V (I am just a beginner). If it helps, I am using a windows VM on a mac.

Comment: For mac, check the link below about how to create the Android emulator. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=macos&pivots=macos  You could check the logs. In the link, check the part of `Viewing Device Manager logs`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?pivots=macos

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look for sure.

Comment: Any update? Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes, I ended up just using the Mac version

Comment: Does the coment help you?

Comment: It appears the fix will be released soon: "A fix for this issue has been internally implemented and is being prepared for release. We’ll update you once it becomes available for download." -- Microsoft. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1052380/message-when-creating-android-device-invalid-emula.html